Playwright doesn't seem to be fullfilling route in trace viewer
I am trying to set up some playwright tests such that some basic auth and user routes are intercepted and spoofed.  The test looks something like this:
test('Mocks the user and session calls', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.route('*/**/user', async (route) => {
    await route.fulfill({
      status: 200,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      body: JSON.stringify(<a_user_object>),
    })
  })

  await page.goto('/homepage')
})

When I run this test in the playwright ui mode (i.e. npx playwright test --ui), it says the route is fullfilled, but it there is no place for me to see the fake data that I fullfilled it with

Clicking on the request itself, the response and body tabs are empty:

Looking in the UI, the user name and information is not being rendered, and logging the user object shows it as undefined.  Running this in the terminal is the same - tests will start failing if I assert that an element with the username contains the expected username, etc.
Am I doing something wrong here?  My methods for trying to intercept and spoof an api response seem taken straight out of the playwright docs.  (Note I also tried doing fullfill({ json: <a_user_object> }), with no change in results.)
I am using playwright 1.43.1

If your tests are failing, please share a runnable [mcve]. The code looks fine to me.

@ggorlen I can potentially set up a repo that mimic's my project, but obviously setting up a project using all the same tooling, with playwright, is alot of work.  My initial question is really whether or not what I'm seeing in the playwright UI is correct - the network calls say "fullfilled", but there is nowhere to confirm what they were fullfilled with.  The playwright docs suggest you should be able to see this in their ui, but that doesn't seem to be the case?

Yeah, it should be visible in the network tab. I ran a simple test and confirmed that this was the case using a similar "mock then goto" setup as you show, so there must be something specific to your project here. It shouldn't be too much work if you start from scratch rather than stripping down, as suggested in the MRE link above. The reprex should be in the question itself.

@ggorlen so you inspired me and you were correct, setting up the simplest possible reprex I could took less than 10 minutes...and it also worked as expected.  The api requests that I intercepted and fullfilled had their fake data showing property in the network tab do indeed show that fake data in the body tab.  My actual project is of course much more complex, but all the same basic peices are in place.  So I wonder what strange things I've done would cause the route to show as fullfilled, but not to have an actual body in the response?

OK, that's good. I would say if you have something simple working, then another complex case not working, you can either introduce complexity step by step to the minimal example until it breaks, or take pieces out of the complex case step by step until it is no longer broken.

I learned why this is happening.  Playwright behaves differently than something like cypress in that when all test commands within a test block in playwright are done running, playwright stops executing code in the page and (I think) does some kind of browser close.  So in the following case:
test("Mocks a simple api call", async ({ page }) => {
  page.route(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/4",
    async (route) =>
      await route.fulfill({
        json: { id: "343", title: "A faked response" },
      })
  );

  await page.goto("http://localhost:3000/");
  // No further command
});

Once Playwright executes the goto command, the test is over, and code in the browser stops running.  So in this test, if you have some UI that renders "A faked response", playwright will never actually render it, because it closes the browser before anything actually renders.  Similarly, the fullfilled response will not show up in the playwright UI.  However, in this case:
test("Mocks a simple api call", async ({ page }) => {
  page.route(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/4",
    async (route) =>
      await route.fulfill({
        json: { id: "343", title: "A faked response" },
      })
  );

  await page.goto("http://localhost:3000/");
  await expect(page.getByText('A faked response')).toBeInViewport()
});

In this case, we're waiting for something to show up on screen, so playwright will not close the browser, but rather wait for that testable text node.  The UI test runner waits until the UI is available, and as such, waits until the route is fullfilled (and the playwright UI shows the body response in its UI).
One trick I found, at least for debugging these scenarios, is the waitForLoadState function.  Playwright will keep the browser open and leave it running until the network calls are all done:
test("Mocks a simple api call", async ({ page }) => {
  page.route(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/4",
    async (route) =>
      await route.fulfill({
        json: { id: "343", title: "A faked response" },
      })
  );

  await page.goto("http://localhost:3000/");
  await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle');
});

In the above test, we're not necessarily asserting anything, but at least in the playwright UI, we can see that the route is fullfilled with the body we gave it, and the UI in the test runner will show what renders once that call is fullfilled.  page.waitForTimeout(X000) also works well.  In a real test, having the last command be waitForLoadState('networkidle') or waitForTimeout wouldn't be very useful. But for debugging your tests, this was extremely helpful, and solves the original question.
